# Where to ask: What is the length of a snap (of the fingers)?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

The question I want to find an answer to is:

What is the duration of a snap (of the fingers)? When someone says, "it's ridiculously fast, it's like [snap]", what is the duration of the snap sound?

Update: Asked here: [What is the duration of a snap?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118601/what-is-the-duration-of-a-snap?stw=2)

Comment: perhaps Physics?  Not sure how much that site gets into applied vs theoretical questions.

Comment: I suppose Biology or Photography might be interested too, but this question could use a lot more definition if it's going to get a single objective answer (and not get put on hold as unclear). Duration of sound? Motion? For whom? (I'd advise picking a specific example, e.g., from YouTube.)

Comment: Updated question per @NickStauner's suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Servy has suggested, Physics seems like the best candidate for a question of the duration of a sound. See the [acoustics](/questions/tagged/acoustics) [tag wiki](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/acoustics/info):

> Acoustics is the interdisciplinary science that deals with the study of all mechanical waves in gases, liquids, and solids including vibration, sound, ultrasound and infrasound. Applications of acoustics are for instance the audio and noise control industries.

[Here's a good example of an answer involving the duration of brief sound](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/60922/36804).

I'm guessing the duration will vary somewhat (especially if there are any reverberation characteristics involved in a recording that is measured), so you might also want to specify a few examples and whether you're interested in excluding reverberation/echo (I assume you would be, and this might make the question a little easier to answer).